# Avoid race condition when incrementing a counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have posted on this topic before, but as yet I have not had much luck. I put it down down to a bad question on my part. This time I have made a short compilable example that displays the bad behavior i'm trying to avoid. I hope this is appreciated.

The problem is two (or more) threads are set to run the same process and their "id's" determine which part of the variable data they operate on. Currently both threads will update the counter.

The current output looks like this,

```
tid = 0, var[tid] = 0
tid = 0, var[tid] = 1
tid = 0, var[tid] = 2
tid = 0, var[tid] = 3
tid = 0, var[tid] = 4
tid = 0, var[tid] = 5
tid = 0, var[tid] = 6
tid = 0, var[tid] = 7
tid = 0, var[tid] = 8
tid = 0, var[tid] = 9
tid = 1, var[tid] = 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The desired output should be like this...

```
tid = 0, var[tid] = 0
tid = 1, var[tid] = 0
tid = 0, var[tid] = 1
tid = 1, var[tid] = 1
tid = 0, var[tid] = 2
tid = 1, var[tid] = 2
tid = 0, var[tid] = 3
tid = 1, var[tid] = 3 etc.
```

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Ive updated the answer with code that works as intended.

[Note that efficiency is important here, I want to complete the process as quickly as possible]

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int var[2];
int mT;
int mTotalSamples;
boost::mutex mCountMutex;
boost::thread *threadMap[2];

using namespace std;

void process()
{
    int tid = 1;

    // sleep for 1 seconds - just to make sure threadMap 
    // has been assigned (only ncessary for this demo).
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

    if (threadMap[0]->get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id()){ tid = 0;}

    while ( mT < mTotalSamples ) 
    {
        // perform processing
        var[tid] = mT; 
        // processing complete

        mCountMutex.lock(); // (a thread waits to aquire mutex)
        cout << "tid = " << tid << ", var[tid] = " << var[tid] << endl;
        mT++;           // How to stop both threads incrementing this?      
        mCountMutex.unlock();       
    }   
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group threads;

    mT = 0;
    mTotalSamples = 10;

    threadMap[0] = threads.create_thread( boost::bind(&process) );
    threadMap[1] = threads.create_thread( boost::bind(&process) );

    threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're hoping that the threads will interleave their access to the mutex.  But there's nothing in your code that enforces that.  If you want operations to commence in a specific sequence, then threads may not be the solution...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the mutex isn't the problem, Each thread should only perform the line, var[tid] = mT; when the counter has been incremented once. But, to be honest i think the use of cout might be confusing the issue.

Comment: For just protecting the counter you can use interlocked opeartions, like `LONG __cdecl InterlockedIncrement(
 LONG volatile *Addend
);
` on windows. Do you really need to protect your `var` variable?

Comment: There's not a lot of point in trying to schedule two threads to cooperate with each other, you may as well forget about threads and just procedurally/manually schedule the operations. Threads are given a certain amount of execution time before switching to another thread. In that time, the thread may complete more work than you want, and forcing one thread to yield to another probably affects the scheduler's efficiency and therefore the overall performance of your app. You should really consider whether threads are necessary for your purpose. Maybe they are, maybe not, but have a think abut it

Comment: @dreamlax Thanks, im aware that this example is somewhat contrived due to the simplification I have applied to make the question digestable. In fact, the one loop may take upto a few seconds with one thread, and in practice I would exectute as many threads as there are cores and divide the update of "var" between those threads equally, thus reducing the time to complete one loop. Threads are definitely applicable to this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your expected output, you want your threads to synchronize after each update. The `boost` library provides [boost::barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/barrier.html) which, if you put a `wait` for it at the start or end of the while-loop in `process`, should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int var[2];
int mT;
int mTotalSamples;
boost::mutex mCountMutex;
boost::thread *threadMap[2];
boost::barrier bar(2);

using namespace std;

void process()
{
    int tid = 1;        

    // sleep for 2 seconds - just to make sure threadMap 
    // has been assigned (only ncessary for this demo).
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));

    if (threadMap[0]->get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id()){ tid = 0;}

    while ( mT < mTotalSamples ) 
    {
        // perform processing
        var[tid] = mT; 
        // processing complete


        bar.wait();
        if (threadMap[0]->get_id() == boost::this_thread::get_id())
        {
            mT++;               
            cout << "var[0] = " << var[0] << endl;
            cout << "var[1] = " << var[1] << endl;                      
        }           
        bar.wait();
    }   
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group threads;

    mT = 0;
    mTotalSamples = 10;

    threadMap[0] = threads.create_thread( boost::bind(&process) );
    threadMap[1] = threads.create_thread( boost::bind(&process) );

    threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlexS: Ok, I've approved your edit, thanks! Btw, is it really necessary, in your application, to have two calls to `bar.wait()`? I would have thought that a single one at the top of the loop would suffice.

Comment: Well, I think so, but I may be wrong. Without it I think there is a chance that thread 2 could do, var[tid] = mT; before thread 1 has manged to increment mT. The second barrier ensures this definitely does not happen.

Comment: @AlexS: Could you verify this? Synchronization points such as barriers can degrade parallel performance significantly, so you should use them as sparingly as possible!

Comment: I think two are necessary to be sure, but it will only become clear if the amount of processing is increased to a realistic size. i.e. if var[0] represents 5 million operations and var[1] represents 20 million operations, then thread 1 would increment the counter before thread 2 finished its work.

Comment: @AlexS: Ok, but then wouldn't it just suffice to have the barrier at the *bottom* of the loop, i.e. after the counter increment?

Comment: Same problem, there is no guarantee that thread 2 will finish its work before thread 1 increments the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Make this `int mT;` local in process() - not global. 
Or you need a `int mT[2];`
Then you would not need mutexes.

Comment: thanks for your comment, although adding a second counter does not help for my needs. Again, this is simply down to me watering down my problem into a simpler one, to make the question readable, the context is lost somewhat.